# Failed opening required /symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php

Tags: symfony, docker, phpunit

I am currently developing a REST Api using Symfony 4.2, and deploying using Docker (`php-fpm`).

When trying to run tests with phpunit in the built container (setting up for ci), it does fail, giving the following output:

```sh
$ docker run api:latest bin/phpunit

PHP Warning:  require(/srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /srv/api/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /srv/api/bin/phpunit:19
PHP   3. include() /srv/api/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:244
PHP   4. require() /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:4
PHP   5. ComposerAutoloaderInitfa3eadee0e53d49c951bc803cfc74f21::getLoader() /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/autoload.php:7
PHP   6. composerRequirefa3eadee0e53d49c951bc803cfc74f21() /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:56
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /srv/api/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /srv/api/bin/phpunit:19
PHP   3. include() /srv/api/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:244
PHP   4. require() /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:4
PHP   5. ComposerAutoloaderInitfa3eadee0e53d49c951bc803cfc74f21::getLoader() /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/autoload.php:7
PHP   6. composerRequirefa3eadee0e53d49c951bc803cfc74f21() /srv/api/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:56
```

Composer does install all required packages, including dev-packages. This is the composer output:

```sh
Package operations: 94 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

    [...]

You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file

Prefetching 10 packages � �
  - Downloading (100%)

Package operations: 10 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-cs-fixer/diff (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/xdebug-handler (1.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/semver (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer (v2.14.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/phpunit-bridge (v4.2.3): Loading from cache
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

Generated autoload files containing 50 classes
```

The files named in the error message do exist:

```sh
$ ls -al vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge
total 88
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 Feb 21 12:59 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 21 12:59 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            34 Feb 21 12:59 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1296 Feb 21 12:59 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2687 Feb 21 12:59 ClockMock.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           868 Feb 21 12:59 CoverageListener.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         13954 Feb 21 12:59 DeprecationErrorHandler.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6013 Feb 21 12:59 DnsMock.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1065 Feb 21 12:59 LICENSE
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Feb 21 12:59 Legacy
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           500 Feb 21 12:59 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           896 Feb 21 12:59 SymfonyTestsListener.php
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Feb 21 12:59 Tests
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Feb 21 12:59 TextUI
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Feb 21 12:59 bin
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1330 Feb 21 12:59 bootstrap.php # <-----
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1400 Feb 21 12:59 composer.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           914 Feb 21 12:59 phpunit.xml.dist
$ ls -al bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer
total 268
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb 10 12:03 .
drwxr-xr-x   14 root     root          4096 Feb 10 12:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13459 Feb 10 12:03 ClassLoader.php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1070 Feb 10 12:03 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         83087 Feb 10 12:03 autoload_classmap.php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           440 Feb 10 12:03 autoload_files.php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           214 Feb 10 12:03 autoload_namespaces.php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           765 Feb 10 12:03 autoload_psr4.php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2414 Feb 10 12:03 autoload_real.php # <-----
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         93179 Feb 10 12:03 autoload_static.php
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         48783 Feb 10 12:03 installed.json
```

When executing the tests in my (windows) development environment (where the `src/` directory is mounted onto `srv/api/`, executed via `docker-compose exec php bin/phpunit`), everything is working as expected.

**EDIT:**

```sh
# Run from where i ran  ls -al vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge
$ pwd
/srv/api

$ ls -la /srv
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 21 13:16 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 21 13:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 21 13:17 api
```

Comment: Can you pls do `ls -la /srv` in container, and `echo $PWD` at the dir where you run `ls -al vendor/composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge` above.

Comment: @DuyPhan Edited my question

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. It seems to me that something is wrong with the symlinks, but my linux knowledge is very limited. Please keep me updated if you find a solution or workaround...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ffouillet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143535/6945068) brought me onto the right path.

Even after reinstalling `symfony/phpunit-bridge` with composer, I couldn't run tests via `bin/phpunit`. I had to call the `simple-phpunit` script directly.

I ended up adding a build step for the test image in my Dockerfile, with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit"]
CMD ["--coverage-text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but with a Windows Wamp Environment (i copy pasted my project sources from linux to windows). I managed to solve the problem by removing symfony/phpunit-bridge (composer remove), then manually deleted the .phpunit dir and phpunit file in my project bin dir and then by reinstalling symfony/phpunit-bridge with composer.
Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error in Lando

The solution was very simple (I personally executed all of this inside the appserver container)

- Remove the vendor folder `rm -rf vendor/`
- Reinstall everything with `composer install`
- Run the Symfony command `bin/simple-phpunit` (on the first execution this command installs all the necessary php-unit related bundles first)

That's it. Hope it work for you too.